# Disable AutoComplete in MVC for IE & Chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

I have my login.cshtml page where the password textbox shows the auto complete option, and I need to disable this. Below is my code.

```
<div id="login">
    @using (Html.BeginForm(MVC.Account.Login())) {

        <div>@Html.ValidationSummary(true)</div>

        <div>@Html.LabelledTextBoxFor(m => m.Username)</div>
        <div>@Html.LabelledPasswordFor(m => m.Password)</div>
    }
</div>
```

How do I disable the auto-complete option which should work both in IE & Chrome?

if I use this below code then i'm getting an error as "No overload method `LabelledPasswordFor` taking 2 arguments".

```
@Html.LabelledPasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { autocomplete = "off" })

public static MvcHtmlString LabelledPasswordFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
    {
    var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
    var displayName = html.RawDisplayNameFor(expression);
    var editor = html.PasswordFor(expression, metadata.IsRequired ? (object)new { placeholder = displayName, @class = "requiredInput" } : new { placeholder = displayName });
    var validator = html.ValidationMessageFor(expression);
    return new MvcHtmlString(editor.ToHtmlString() + validator.ToHtmlString());
    }
```

Comment: What is LabelledPasswordFor? Is this a function from a 3rd party library or a custom one?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I would recommend wrapping your code in code formatting so it can be read easier. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: It looks like `LabelledPasswordFor` is **not** a built-in method provided by ASP.NET MVC. If you provide a link to its public documentation (or even better: all the overloads that it supports) then we may be able to help. Otherwise I'm afraid it's going to be problematic.

Comment: public static MvcHtmlString LabelledPasswordFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
   { var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);var displayName = html.RawDisplayNameFor(expression);var editor = html.PasswordFor(expression, metadata.IsRequired ? (object)new { placeholder = displayName, @class = "requiredInput" } : new { placeholder = displayName });var validator = html.ValidationMessageFor(expression);
            return new MvcHtmlString(editor.ToHtmlString() + validator.ToHtmlString());
        }

Comment: @PeterB - Please find the method for labelledPasswordFor . Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `LabelledPasswordFor` is of your own implementation, you should be able to change it to also support `autocomplete`. Below is an example.

I opted to call it using `true/false`, which is then translated to `"on" / "new-password"` so the exact details of the attribute are not the callers concern.

```
public static MvcHtmlString LabelledPasswordFor<TModel, TValue>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression,
    bool autocomplete = true)
{
    var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
    var displayName = html.RawDisplayNameFor(expression);

    var htmlAttr = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    htmlAttr.Add("placeholder", displayName);
    htmlAttr.Add("autocomplete", autocomplete ? "on" : "new-password");
    htmlAttr.Add("class", metadata.IsRequired ? "requiredInput" : "");
    var editor = html.PasswordFor(expression, htmlAttr);

    var validator = html.ValidationMessageFor(expression);
    return new MvcHtmlString(editor.ToHtmlString() + validator.ToHtmlString());
}
```

Usage:

```
<div>@Html.LabelledPasswordFor(m => m.Password, autocomplete: false)</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @PeterB  for the reply. It is now giving me a tag as below but the autocomplete still happens inspite of being "Off" <input name="Password" class="requiredInput input-validation-error" id="Password" aria-invalid="true" aria-describedby="Password-error" type="password" placeholder="Password" data-val-required="Password is required" data-val="true" autocomplete="off">

Comment: See my update, it turns out that Chrome needs "new-password" to prevent password auto fill. Hopefully other browsers agree...

Comment: Thank you. This "new-password" is working in chrome but not in IE . :(

Answer (score 0):

Setting HTML's input element **autocomplete** attribute to "off" value should prevent autocomplete:

```
@Html.LabelledPasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { autocomplete = "off" })
```

BTW, you could disable autocomplete feature for the whole form(all inputs inside  the form will be affected) using

```
Html.BeginForm(action, controller, FormMethod.Post, new { autocomplete="off"})
```

Comment: Thanks. But this gives me an error saying No overload for method "LabelledPasswordFor" takes 2 arguments.

Comment: Please see the @Peter B 's answer in case of your custom implementation of LabelledPasswordFor. I thought initially that LabeledPasswordFor just wraps standard MVC's implementation of PasswordFor with the same or extended signature.